# Using Rails' ActionView Helpers outside of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What do I need to do to get [`number_to_human_size`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001688) to work in a script outside of rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try bringing in enough of the various Rails gems to support it (starting with ActionPack and continuing with ActiveSupport), but you're definitely going to have to bring in quite a lot - it eventually needs to have a locale system initialized with locale files for translation.

dvyjones suggestion will be much quicker if you don't need that localization.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this method](http://gist.github.com/260184) should work. I haven't tested it though, and it doesn't accept any options other than the number.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [alchemist](http://github.com/toastyapps/alchemist), a ruby library for converting between lots of different units. I haven't used it myself, I've only heard about it on rubyinside.

Answer (score 0):

Decide whether or not you care about all the internationalization support the method implements and then copy and paste the rest.